# Do the rules of chametz apply to IV nutrition?

Tags: halacha, passover, medicine, chametz-leaven

Does chametz apply only to what is eaten orally or to any type of nutrition / food regardless of how it is ingested?

Comment: You're not aloud to benefit from chametz on Pesach, so... assuming you're not talking about pikuach nefesh I think it's pretty clear that you couldn't use chametzdich IVs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are really two parts to your question. One is:     do the rules of Chametz apply regardless how it is ingested?

http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-mitzvos-cosmetics.htm

> On Pesach, one may not consume, own or derive benefit from items that
>   contain derivatives of the chameishes minei dagan - wheat, barley,
>   spelt, oats, and rye.

The second part of your question is regarding an IV, where often the one who gets such nutrition is sick. There it would depend on availability of non-Chametz options, how sick, etc. A question for each individual to his local rabbi.

See also from [CRC-Chicago](http://www.crcweb.org/Sappirim/Sappirim%2012%20%28Apr%202008%29.pdf) that says that most intravenous does not contain Chometz and even if it did one who is incapacitated is allowed to take it.